# stackoverflow "Related Questions"

Tags: ajax

There are other websites too that have this feature "Related...".  What impresses me though is they open up right there on the page as soon as you tab away from title field I think. Are they not querying the database every single time someone enters a new title?

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to implement a "related questions" bar similar to the one here, so I don't think it belongs on Meta.

Comment: Agreed; this is not "meta". Migrate votes have been voided.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they are cached at the time the question was asked. The cache is probably not touched again unless the question's title is changed. At least for SO, I've never seen a newer question appear in the Related Questions field.

So to answer your question, no, the database is only queried once (or more if the title changes).